Energy stored in EM fields are non-retrievable?

I came across this while I was reading Griffith's. I've been used to ElectroDynamics for about 6 months now, And I just tried the math for energy in EM fields. I came across this. It states that work on a charge due to an EM field is given by the above expression. I have a few questions... Please try to use math to explain as much as possible (Intuition is also appreciated though)

why is work done negative? I suppose the first term decreases or something to make the resultant positive, but the second term?
I'm hoping the second term is positive. This is because if energy flows back into the field from the accelerating charge, Does that mean some energy will always be stored in the fields that cannot be given to any charges? Especially if we have an EM wave on whose path is an electron, would the electron gain the total energy stored in the EM field due to this EM wave?

Please try not to include relativistic effects unless it is necessary to answer my question (which I guess isn't necessary).

Welcome to Physics SE. Good question! I would strongly recommend copying equations and text out from screeshots, since not everyone can see screenshots, and if someone looks up something related to your question, it might not get indexed by the search engine.

$dW/dt$ represents the rate at which the electromagnetic field does work on the charges in a volume $\mathcal{V}$.  Specifically, since the rate of work done on an object is given by $P = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{v}$, we have
$$
\frac{dW}{dt} = \int_\mathcal{V} (\rho \vec{E} \, d\tau) \cdot \vec{v} = 
\int_\mathcal{V} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{J} \, d\tau 
$$
since $\vec{J} = \rho \vec{v}$.
As this happens, the charges will change their kinetic energy.  The other answer (and Griffiths) then show that this integral can be rewritten in terms of two other integrals.  This can then be interpreted by then saying that if the charges in $\mathcal{V}$ increase their kinetic energy ($dW/dt > 0$), this must be due to one or both of the following effects:

The energy of the EM fields inside the volume is decreasing (i.e., the first integral is decreasing with $t$.)
There must be a net flux of electromagnetic field energy into the volume, through its surface (i.e., the second integral is negative.  Note that negative flux means $\vec{E} \times \vec{B}$ points opposite $d\vec{a}$.)

The first case can be thought of as analogous to a conversion of potential energy into kinetic energy for a closed system.  The second can be thought of as an addition of energy into the system.

Thank you, your answer was very satisfying. Is it possible that both the Terms cooperate so that net energy carried by a particular EM wave is converted totally into Kinetic energy?

@CodeKeys:  It's well known that it's impossible for a single charge to completely absorb a photon, and the proof deals entirely with concepts that apply equally well to EM waves (energy and momentum conservation.)  So I would expect that that it wouldn't be possible for a single charge to completely absorb an EM wave.  It might be possible for a configuration of multiple charges to do so, though.

Thank you, this was my initial conclusion. But for some reason, I thought I was making a mistake somewhere.

We start from the formula for the energy density
$$
u(t, \vec{x})= \frac{1}{2} \left( \epsilon_0 \vec{E}(t, \vec{x})^2+\frac{1}{\mu_0} \vec{B}(t, \vec{x})^2 \right) \tag{1} \label{1}
$$
of the electromagnetic field. Differentiating \eqref{1} with repect to time $t$ and inserting the two Maxwell equations
$$
\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}(t, \vec{x})=- \frac{\partial \vec{B}(t, \vec{x})}{\partial t}, \qquad \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{B}(t, \vec{x})=\mu_0 \left( \vec{j}(t, \vec{x})+ \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec{E}(t, \vec{x})}{\partial t} \tag{2} \label{2}  \right) $$
yields
$$\begin{align} \frac{\partial u(t, \vec{x}) }{\partial t}&= \epsilon_0 \vec{E}(t, \vec{x}) \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{E}(t, \vec{x})}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{\mu_0} \vec{B}(t, \vec{x}) \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{B}(t, \vec{x})}{\partial t}      \\[5pt] &= -\vec{j}(t,\vec{x}) \cdot \vec{E}(t, \vec{x})+\frac{1}{\mu_0}\underbrace{\left[\vec{E}(t, \vec{x}) \cdot \left(\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{B}(t, \vec{x}) \right) - \vec{B}(t, \vec{x}) \cdot \left( \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}(t, \vec{x}) \right) \right]}_{-\vec{\nabla} \cdot \left(\vec{E}(t, \vec{x}) \times \vec{B}(t, \vec{x}) \right)}.
      \end{align}  \tag{3}$$
Thus, the electromagnetic energy density $u$ and the Poynting vector $\vec{S}=\vec{E} \times \vec{B}/\mu_0$ satisfy the continuity equation
$$\frac{\partial u(t, \vec{x})}{\partial t}+ \vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{S}(t, \vec{x})=-\vec{j}(t, \vec{x}) \cdot\vec{E}(t, \vec{x}) \tag{4} \label{4} $$ with the additional term $-\vec{j} \cdot \vec{E}$ on the right-hand-side (RHS). Integrating \eqref{4} over a (time-independent) volume $V$ containing all charges present, the integral version of \eqref{4} becomes
$$\frac{d}{dt} \underbrace{\int\limits_V \! d^3x \, u(t, \vec{x})}_{\mathcal{E}_V}+ \int\limits_{\partial V}\! d\vec{a} \cdot \vec{S}(t, \vec{x}) =- \int\limits_V \! d^3x \, \vec{j}(t, \vec{x}) \cdot \vec{E}(t, \vec{x}), \tag{5} \label{5}    $$ where the integral theorem of Gauss was used. The RHS of \eqref{5} has a simple physical interpretation. Assuming, for simplicity, a distribution of point particles with charges $q_a$ and trajectories $\vec{r}_a(t)$,
$$
\rho(t, \vec{x})= \sum\limits_a q_a \, \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{r}_a(t)), \quad \vec{j}(t, \vec{x}) = \sum\limits_a q_a \, \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{r}_a(t)) \, \dot{\vec{r}}_a(t), \tag{6} \label{6}$$ the RHS of \eqref{5} becomes
$$-\int\limits_V \, d^3x \, \vec{j}(t, \vec{x}) \cdot \vec{E}(t, \vec{x})= -\sum\limits_a q_a \, \dot{\vec{r}}_a(t) \cdot \vec{E}(t, \vec{r}_a(t)). \tag{7} \label{7}   $$
Disregarding potential self-energy problems,  $$\dot{\vec{r}}_a(t) \cdot \underbrace{ q_a \vec{E}(t, \vec{r}_a(t))}_{\vec{F}_a} \tag{8}$$ is the work (per unit time)  done by the electromagnetic field on the charge $q_a$, being equivalent to the time derivative $\dot{T}_a$ of the kinetic energy $T_a$ of particle $a$. With $T:=\sum\limits_a T_a$, \eqref{5} can be recast into the form
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (T + \mathcal{E}_V)= -\int\limits_{\partial V} d\vec{a} \cdot \vec{S}. \tag{9} \label{9}
$$
The signs in \eqref{9} make perfectly sense. As we have assumed that the charges are confined in the volume $V$, the total energy of the system "electromagnetic field in $V$ plus charges in $V$" decreases if electromagnetic radiation escapes through the boundary $\partial V$, i.e. $$\int\limits_{\partial V} d\vec{a} \cdot \vec{S} >0.$$ On the other hand, the energy $T+ \mathcal{E}_V$ increases if radiation is sent into the volume $V$, i.e. $$\int\limits_{\partial V} d\vec{a} \cdot \vec{S} < 0.$$ Let us finally assume a situation where the RHS of \eqref{9} vanishes. (Suppose, for instance, that $V$ is very large and both the charges and the electromagnetic field stay within $V$ during our period of observation.) In this case, we have $T+ \mathcal{E}_V= {\rm const.}$, so increasing  $T$ implies decreasing $\mathcal{E}_V$ (the charges gain kinetic energy by absorbing electromagnetic radiation) or vice versa (the charges loose kinetic energy by emitting radiation).
Concerning your specific questions: What makes you believe that the RHS of your eq. (8.9) should be negative? Depending on the physical situation, the time derivative of the electromagnetic energy contained in the volume $V$ can be positive or negative. The same applies to the surface integral (consider the cases $d\vec{a}$ parallel/antiparallel to $\vec{S}$).

Thank you so much! I was fixated on a particular scenario in which An electron obtains energy from an EM wave. But you've not answered my last question, If an EM wave is emitted carrying a certain amount of energy, can the entire energy be converted to the kinetic energy of a particle under any circumstance?

@CodeKeys Are you are asking for the (classical) scattering cross section of an electromagnetic wave on a (free) electron? You can find it in any text-book on electrodynamics or compute it yourself easily. At the quantum level (QED), the process $\gamma e^- \to e^-$ is forbidden by energy-momentum conservation but the  cross section of Compton scattering  $e^- \gamma \to e^- \gamma$  tends to the classical result in the limit $\hbar \omega << m_e c^2$ (Thomson limit) with $\hbar \omega$ being the photon energy in the reference frame where the electron is initially at rest.

The way I see it, If an EM wave gives its energy to an electron, that is by doing some work on it, the electron accelerates and thus emits an  EM wave of a fraction of that energy. So the Energy of a wave can never be fully converted to kinetic energy since a part of the energy leaves again as an EM wave. Am I wrong somewhere? Also, I'm not able to solve particular problems even in classical Electro dynamics because of my lack of knowledge of partial differential equations. That is why I'm asking these without working out.

@CodeKeys 1. Your qualitative description of Thomson scattering is correct. 2. Learning how to solve partial differential equations occuring in classical electrodynamics is the main goal of any good text book on the subject. I don't have your book at hand, but I guess all this is explained in detail in some later chapters.

Let's say $dW/dt$, the rate at which work is done (i.e. power) is positive. Where does that come from?
Well, it either comes from decreasing the energy stored in the electromagnetic fields, which would make the first term on the RHS positive. Or, there could be an inward energy flow, perhaps carried by electromagnetic waves - this would make the second term on the RHS positive because by convention, $d\vec{a}$ points outwards from a closed surface and $(\vec{E}\times\vec{B})\cdot d\vec{a}$ would be negative.
